# Google Colab - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i am trying to train YOLOv3 with custom dataset on Google Colab. I uploaded my folders, weights etc. When I run my train.py, I get path error. I run the code like this:

```
!python3 "drive/TrainYourOwnYolo/2_Training/Train_YOLO.py"
```

The error says,

```
content/TrainYourOwnYolo/2_Training/dataset/img20.jpg is not found.
```

As I understand on Colab, my all folders are under drive folder. I don't understand why yolo is trying to find my dataset under content folder. Do you have any idea?

[image][image]

Comment: How exactly did you upload the dataset, and where? Do you use Google Drive or not? If yes, how have you mounted it?

Comment: I use google drive. I mounted them like this:

!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive

Comment: What do you get with `!ls /drive`? Do you see any directory `TrainYourOwnYolo/`?

Comment: It is empty.I dont see anything in that folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it seems, you have uploaded your data to `/drive/TrainYourOwnYolo/`, and not to `/content/TrainYourOwnYolo/`, where your script is looking.

The `/content` folder is normally used by Colab when saving, in case you don't use Google Drive. But you have mounted your Google Drive under `/drive`, so your notebook unsurprisingly fails to find the files.

You should change the file paths in your `Train_YOLO.py"` script to replace references to `/content` with `/drive`.

If this is not possible, you can find the `/content` folder on the file catalogue on the left of your Colab notebook:

[image]

and by right-clicling on it, you'll see an option for uploading files there.